# Using h1-h6 headings exclusively for article and excerpt titles

Tags: html, seo, html-heading

I know how headings are supposed to work, but in any single text I never get to use anything more than the H1.

A few years back, in some magazine-style sites, I saw this practice where H2 to H6 headings were used as excerpt titles - links to other articles. I started doing the same myself, without really knowing how proper the code is (as there is no direct hierarchy, just an implied sense of importance).

So, for example, I would use H1 to wrap the title of the main article, than a couple of H2s for the "previous post" and "next post" titles, a few more H3s for titles of "articles in the same category" and so on.

Validators seem to be ok with it, but still I'm not sure if it's fine semantically or seo-wise. Does it make sense or is it stupid?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following Hierarchy for htags in you blogs

```
<h1>This is post Title</h1>
<p>Paragraph goes here</p>
<h2>This is used for Paragraph Title</h2> // Semantic Keywrods can be used to gain benefit.
<p>Paragraph goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph goes here</p>
<h2>This is used for Paragraph Title</h2> // Semantic Keywrods can be used to gain benefit.
<p>Paragraph goes here</p>
<h3>Title within paragraph</h3>
<h4>Introductory Paragraph of About Yourself or Company</h4>
<p>Introductory Paragraph goes here.</p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Introductory Paragraph of About Yourself or Company" wouldn't be an h4 unless that section were part of the h3 above it ("Title within paragraph"). Based on the copy it sounds like this is a separate section, so it would likely be an h2 actually.